# How do I correctly declare associations between my profile and comment models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I would like to know if I have correctly declared the association between my profile and comment modules so that I can display the profile image of the current user above the comment that they just created for themselves and all other users to see.

I have a Profile model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :address, :firstname, :lastname, :mobile , :user_id, :photo
   attr_accessor :image_file_name, :image_content_type, :image_file_size, :image_updated_at

   has_attached_file :photo

   validates_attachment_presence :photo
   validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
   validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']

   belongs_to :user
   has_many :comments
   has_many :post
end
```

I have a comments model:

```
 class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :post
     belongs_to :profile
     attr_accessible :body, :commenter, :photo
 end
```

As you can see above the profile model also belongs_to a user and each comment belongs to a (blog)post.

I would like to make the photo (or profile image) of the current user appear beside a comment that the user has created. At the moment I only have functionality to allow users to enter a "name" when creating a comment.

Can someone steer me in the right direction? Also is this a common problem and what is it called?

Let me know if you need me to post anymore code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created the correct database migrations the associations you have copied down seem correct

also that when you create the comment you have correctly attached the post and profile to the comment record which you should be able to test.

given that you have a `@post` variable containing the current post

```
@post.comments.each do |comment|
  # to get the photo object
  # you may need to call photo_url depending on the gem you used
  comment.profile.photo

  # then to get the name 
  comment.profile.firstname
  comment.profile.lastname

  # or from the user object
  comment.profile.user.name
end
```

if you need to get the details from the user model you should look into adding a `belongs_to :user, through: :profile' relation. However please double check that syntax.

that way you could have

```
comment.user.name
# instead of
comment.profile.user.name
```

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how to attach the profile to the comment. I have attached the post to the comment already. Also, I am only focused on making the photo appear. Any pointers?

Comment: when you create the comment you just need to pass the current active profile into the form. Also is the attribute commenter supposed to relate to the profile? they are using two very different names. How do they know about each other. please read through this page to work out your relationship management http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Hi the commenter attribute will not need to relate to the profile as I want to remove it and put the profile image in its place. I don't think I mentioned this above. I am struggling with how to identify the current active profile. I have tried many variations such as current_user.profile . Thanks for the link.